# The Type field is being left out in biblatex citation

Tags: biblatex, citing

Alright I have a citation that needs to look like the below:

> Macdonald, A. & Reich, A. (Producers) & Garland, P. (Director). (2015). Ex Machina [Motion picture]. United Kingdom: Universal Studios.

However, it is leaving out the "[Motion picture]" part of the citaiton when generating it as shown here:

> Schnabel, J. (Director), & Kennedy, K. & Kilik, J. (Producer). (2007). The diving bell and the butterfly. France: Pathé/Miramax Films.

How can I get biblatex to include the "Motion picture" field?

My entry:

```
@movie{divingbell2007,
    title={The Diving Bell and the Butterfly},
    year={2007},
    producer={Kennedy, K. and Kilik, J.},
    director={Schnabel, J.},
    type={Motion Picture},
    publisher={France: Path\'{e}/Miramax Films}
}
```

I am using a modified field for this:

```
\documentclass[doc]{apa6}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, natbib]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}
{american-apa}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\DeclareLabelname[movie]{
    \field{director}
    \field{producer}
}

\begin{document}
\title{The Diving Bell and the Butterfly Journal}
\shorttitle{Diving Bell and Butterfly Journal}
\author{Henry J Schmale}
\affiliation{Harrisburg University of Science and Technology}
\date{\today}
\abstract{Journal for \textit{The Diving Bell and the Butterfly}}
\nocite{divingbell2007}
\maketitle

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a complete example we can compile rather than fragments of code. A proper example is much more useful.

Comment: @cfr posted full example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, you need to use the `entrysubtype` field and not `type`. I couldn't find any `biblatex-apa` documentation on that, but the code suggests it. A rule of thumb *seems* to be that `entrysubtype` appears closer to the `title` than `type` does.

Then you will also need

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[movie]{entrysubtype}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
```

and are good to go. (From what I could see in `apa.bbx`, maybe even `\DeclareFieldFormat{entrysubtype}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}` would be OK.)

MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@movie{divingbell2007,
    title={The Diving Bell and the Butterfly},
    year={2007},
    producer={Kennedy, K. and Kilik, J.},
    director={Schnabel, J.},
    entrysubtype={Motion Picture},
    publisher={France: Path\'{e}/Miramax Films}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, natbib]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}
{american-apa}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareLabelname[movie]{
    \field{director}
    \field{producer}
}

\DeclareFieldFormat[movie]{entrysubtype}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{divingbell2007}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `movie` and `video` are in fact the same code in the APA style but are not aliased just in case of future changes. So, the examples in the documentation for APA 7.07:49 and APA 7.07:51 also apply to `movie`. I would tend to use the more generic type `video` and then use `entrysubtype` to specify a film myself.